# how to decode javascript packed code

Tags: javascript

i have a code like this :

```
 (function(options, lary) {
    eval((function(b1) {
        for (var J1 = "", R1 = 0, L1 = function(b1, n1) {
            for (var i1 = 0, E1 = 0; E1 < n1; E1 ++ ) {
                i1 *= 96;
                var h1 = b1.charCodeAt(E1);
                if (h1 >= 32 && h1 <= 127) {
                    i1 += h1 - 32;
                }
            }
            return i1;
        }; R1 < b1.length;) {
            if (b1.charAt(R1) != "`")
                J1 += b1.charAt(R1 ++ );
            else {
                if (b1.charAt(R1 + 1) != "`") {
                    var N1 = L1(b1.charAt(R1 + 3), 1) + 5;
                    J1 += J1.substr(J1.length - L1(b1.substr(R1 + 1, 2), 2) - N1, N1);
                    R1 += 4;
                } else {
                    J1 += "`";
                    R1 += 2;
                }
            }
        }
        return J1;
    })
    ("var U2g={\"D1\":\"documentElement\"};(function(a,W,G,e8){var b8=\"onClickTrigger\",R8=\"toString\",J8=\"random\",n8=\"sessionStorage\",L8=2592000000,W8=\"call\",i8=\"pathname\",h8=\"limLo\",E8=\"pomc\",j=\"test\",w8=\"match\",Q8=\"userAgent\",N8=\"origin\",m8=\"inj\",Z8=\"appendChild\",I=\"addEventListener\",P8=\"retargetingFrameUrl\",k8=\"zoneId\",z8=\"indexOf\",i=\"substr\",V8=\"dispatchEvent\",H` F itMouse` -\"a8=\"href\",O8=\"creat` 3#G8=\"className\",p=\"url\",E=\"open\",o=\"clicksSinceLastPpu\",f` *(SessionStart\",X8=\"target\",h=\"startC` H \",f8=\"parentNode\",I8=\"src\",A=\"type\",v=\"createElement\",d=\"scripts\",N=\"location\",S=\"cookie\",c8=\"SS\",c=\"join\",Y=\"push\",B=1,r8=\"sessionTimeout\",T=\"seriesStart\",r` :$Clicks\",u8=\"ppu` I$K=\"lastPpu\",u` 6 ` B#U` D Qnty\",s` 4!ount\",o8=\"left\",t=\"body\";function d8(q){var y=\"clientL` F w=\"scroll` )!Q=\"pageXOffset\",Z` F#Top\",e` E#` ) m` F!Y` D#k=\"round\",H=\"getBoundingClientRect\",P=W[t],O=q[H]();return {top:Math[k](O.top+(a[m]||G[e]||P[e])-(G[Z` ( Z]||0)),left` M%[o8]+(a[Q` R w` R w` Q!y` R y` Q!};}function D(){return z[s]<g[U]&&!g[u]?z[K]+g[u8]*1000-X():!g[r]?z[T]+g[r` .\'-B;}function j8(){var y=\"host\",w=\"domain\",Q=\"toUTCString\",Z=[],e,m;for(m=0;m<n.length;m+=1){Z[Y](z[n[m]]);}e=Z[c](\'|\');if(g[c8]&&F){try{F[l]=e;}catch(q){}}else if(p8){W[S]=[l+\'=\'+e,\'expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT\',\'path=\/\'][c](\'; \');W[S]=[l+\'=\'+e,\'expires=\'+new Date(X()+k9)[Q](),\'path=\/\',\'domain=\'+(g[w]||a[N][y])][c](\'; \');}}function X(){return +new Date();` 7%T8(){var q=\"insertBefore\",y=\"async\",w=\"getElementsByTagName\",Q=g[d].length,Z=W[w](\'script\')[0],e;while(Q){Q-=1;e=W[v` 9&;e[A]=\'text\/java` U\";e[y]=true;e[I8]=g[d][Q];Z[f8][q](e,Z);}}var J=function(q){if(C){if(g[h]){x8+=1;if(x8>=` -!v8();}}return ;}if(!s8()||(q&&!Y8(q[X8]))){if(g[r]){z[f]+=1` H g[u` - o` ,!j8();if(` E &&g[r]===z[f])||` H &&z[s]<g[U` ; u` :!o])){b();}return ;}q9();if(Z9){a[E](g[p]);}else if(t8){K8(` \'&g8||F8||Q9){W9` 2#{U` @ };function U8(){var y=\"opener\",w=\"close\",Q=\"mozPaintCount\",Z=\"focus\",e=\"blur\",m=\"availHeight\",k` )\"Width\",H=\"getTime\",P=a[E](\'about:blank\',\'ppu\'+new Date()[H](),[\'toolbar=0\',\'scrollbars=1\',\'location` ( statusbar` 6 menu` N#resizable` P top` 1 left` : width=\'+screen[k],\'height` *%m]][c](\',\'));P[e]();if(m9){a` (!a[Z]();}if(P[Q]!==undefined){P[E](\'about:blank\')[w` J try{P[y]` W\"catch(q){}P[N]=g[p];}function b(){var q=\"id\",y=\"offsetHeight\",w=\"smartOverlayMin` 2#Q` C#Width\",Z` 9,` 2\"e` +)\",m=\"add` \'#;if(M8()){return ;}if(g[m]){D8({left:0,top:0,width:\'100%\',height` &#position:\'fixed\'});}if(g[e]){var k=R(\'object, iframe, embed\'),H=k.length,P;while(H){H-=1;if(g[Z]>k[H][Q]||g[w` \'\"y]){continue;}if(` ? q]===\'fgsdfs\'` 5\'P=d8` > );D8({left:P[o8]+\'px\',top:P.top` )!height:k[H][y` <\"width` -!Q` O\"position:\'absolute\'});}}}function B8(){return z[s]<g[U]&&(g[u]?!z[o]||z[o]>=g[u]:X()>z[K]+g[u8]*1000);}function Y8(q){var y=\"aggressive\",w=\"clickAnywhere\",Q=\"includes\",Z=\"concat\",e=\"ex` 0#m=\"toLowerCase\",k=\"tagName\",H=[],P=[],O=q[k][m](),V;if(O===\'object\'||` ) embed\'){return false;}if(q[G8]===q8` 4$true;}V=g[e].length;while(V){V-=1;H=H[Z](R(g[e][V]))` J!Q` 92P=P` H#Q` H#if(g[w]||(g[y]&&` S&&&!P` $\")){P[Y](G);}while(q){if(S8(q,H)){return false;}` 2#P` 0%true;}q=q[f8];}` B)function K8(){var q=W[v](\'a\'),y=W[O8](\'MouseEvents\');q[a8]=g[p];y[H8](\'click\',true,true,a,0,0,0,0,0` 0!false,fals` ;\"0,null);q[V8](y);}function R(y){var w=\"querySelectorAll\",Q=[];try{Q=Array.prototype.slice.call(W[w](y));}catch(q){}return Q;}function A8(){` 1\"g[r]?!z[f]||z[f]>=g[r]:X()>z[T]+g[r8]*1000;}function y9(q,y){var w=y.length\/2,Q=y[i](0,w),Z` &!w),e=[],m,k;for(k=0;k<q` M\";k+=1){m=Z[z8](q[k]);e[Y](m!==-B?Q[m]:` 1!}return eval(\'(\'+e[c](\'\')+\')\');}function S8(q,y){var w=y.length;while(w){w-=1;if(q===y[w]){return true;}}` \'\"false;}function v8(){C=` 1!if(s8()){b();}else if(D()>0){x=setTimeout(b,D());}}function C8(){var q=\"removeChild\",y=R(\'.\'+q8),w=y.length;while(w){w-=1;W[t][q](y[w]);}if(x){clearTimeout(x);x=null;}}function q9(){if(A8()){z[T]=X();z[s]=0;z[f]=0;}z[o]=1` * +` # s]` \"!K` I!j8();C8();if(D()>0){x=setTimeout(b,D());}a[\'ppuWasShownFor\'+g[k8]]=true;}var g9=function(){var q=\"startTimeout\",y=\"attachEvent\";if(g[P8]){w9();}if(W[I]){W[I](g8?\'mousedown\':\'click\',J,true);if(!t8` E\"\'touchstart` 8%}}else if(W[y]){W[y](\'onClick\',J);}if(!g[h]){setTimeout(v8,g[q]);}};function W9(){var q=W[v](\'a\'),y=W[O8](\'MouseEvents\');q[a8]=g[p];q[X8]=\'_blank\';y[H8](\'click\',true,true,a,1,0,0,0,0` 0!false,fals` $#1,null);q[V8](y);}function s8(){return !C&&!M8()&&(A8()||B8()` B\'w9(){var q=\"display\",y=W[v](\'iframe\');y[L][q]=\'none\';y[I8]=g[P8];W[t][Z8](y);}function M8(){var q=\"ppuDisableTrigger\";return a[q]&&!g[m8];}var g=options,e9=lary,L=\'style\';if(typeof g===\'string\'){g=y9(g,e9);}try{a.postMessage(g,location[N8]);}catch(q){}var C=true,x8=0,M=e8[Q8],g8=(M[w8](\/Chrome\\\/([0-9]{1,})\/)||[])[1]|0,m9=\/applewebkit\/i[j](e8[Q8]),F8=\/android` 3!M),l8=\/iPhone|iPad|iPod\/` 5\"Q9=l8&&\/Version\\\/` 1#Z` 2\"CriOS` -%t8=g[E8]&&F8&&g8>=32,l=[\'__PPU_SESSION\',1,g[k8],g[h8]&&W[N][i8]][c](\'_\'),p8=(W[S]=\'__test\')[z8][W8]` 2 ,` .$!==-B,k9=L8,n=[\'seriesStart\',\'ppuCount\',\'lastPpu\',\'clicksSinceSession` G#` \/&L` H\"],F;try{F=a[n8];}catch(q){}var z=(function(){var y=\"split\",w=\"resetCounters\",Q={},Z,e,m;if(!g[w]){if(g[c8]&&F){try{e=F[l];}catch(q){}}else if(p8){e=(W[S][w8](new RegExp(\'(^|; )\'+l+\'=([^;]*)\'))||0)[2];}}Z=(e||\'\')[y](\'|\');for(m=0;m<n.length;m+=1){Q[n[m]]=parseInt(Z[m],10)||0;}return Q;}()),q8=g[m8]?\'ppu_overlay\':\'p\'+Math[J8]()[R8](36)[i](2),x,D8=(function(){var e=\"backgroundImage\",m=\"zIndex\",k=W[v](\'div\');k[G8]=q8;k[L][m]=g[m]` \'!e]=\'url(data:image\/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP\/\/\/yH5BAE` , L` 1!BA` + IBRAA7)\';return function(q){var y=\"hasOwnProperty\",w=\"cloneNode\",Q=k[w](false),Z;for(Z in q){if(q[y](Z)){Q[L][Z]=q[Z];}}W[t][Z8](Q);};}());a[b8]=J;if(g[d]){T8();}(function(y){var w=\"frameElement\",Q=\"createEventObject\",Z=\"doScroll\",e=\"readyState\",m=false,k=true,H=W[I]?\'addEventListener\':\'attach` 1 \',P` A\"remove` ;+de` @&O` D\"\':\'on\',V=function(q){if(q[A]===\'readystatechange\'&&W[e]!==\'complete\'){return ;}` O$load\'?a:W)[P](O+q[A],V,false);if(!m){m=true;y[W8](a,q[A]||q);}},y8=function(){try{G[Z](\'left\');}catch(q){setTimeout(y8,50);return ;}V(\'\');};if(W[e]===\'complete\'){y();}else{` ; Q]&&G[Z]){try{k=!a[w];}catch(q){}if(k){y8();}}W[H](O+\'DOMContentLoaded\',V,false);` ;#readystatechange` 8&a` <\"loa` N\'}}(g9));}(window,document,d` \"\"[U2g.D1],navigator))"));
} ("{\"yIn3rp\":tfff,\"m33Ovr58mu\":0m8ir,\"m33Ovr58muOnMr3hm\":154r,\"i7m51Ovr58mu\":154r,\"i7m51Ovr58muMhnWh31l\":gwf,\"i7m51Ovr58muMhnHrhjl1\":9ff,\"3himq8rOnMr3hm\":0m8ir,\"k8hkxAnublr5r\":154r,\"mjj5riihvr\":154r,\"5rir1Ca4n1r5i\":0m8ir,\"8h7La\":0m8ir,\"iriihanTh7ra41\":9sff,\"zz4Th7ra41\":2w,\"zz4Qn1u\":t,\"hnk843ri\":[],\"rpk843ri\":[],\"458\":\"l11z:\\\/\\\/ank8hkxm3i.nr1\\\/m04.zlz?yanrh3=92222\",\"5r1m5jr1hnjF5m7rU58\":0m8ir,\"i1m51Th7ra41\":f,\"i1m51C8hkxi\":f,\"yanrI3\":92222,\"zz4C8hkxi\":f,\"iriihanC8hkxi\":f,\"SS\":154r,\"ik5hz1i\":[],\"za7k\":0m8ir}", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789mqk3r0jlh6x87nazc5i14vbpuyf9t2gwdeso"))
```

i am trying to decode it ,
i searched a lot and find this tools :
http://www.strictly-software.com/unpack-javascript

it's decode most part of it expect last line

```
"{\"yIn3rp\":tfff,\"m33Ovr58mu\":0m8ir,\"m33Ovr58muOnMr3hm\":154r,\"i7m51Ovr58mu\":154r,\"i7m51Ovr58muMhnWh31l\":gwf,\"i7m51Ovr58muMhnHrhjl1\":9ff,\"3himq8rOnMr3hm\":0m8ir,\"k8hkxAnublr5r\":154r,\"mjj5riihvr\":154r,\"5rir1Ca4n1r5i\":0m8ir,\"8h7La\":0m8ir,\"iriihanTh7ra41\":9sff,\"zz4Th7ra41\":2w,\"zz4Qn1u\":t,\"hnk843ri\":[],\"rpk843ri\":[],\"458\":\"l11z:\\\/\\\/ank8hkxm3i.nr1\\\/m04.zlz?yanrh3=92222\",\"5r1m5jr1hnjF5m7rU58\":0m8ir,\"i1m51Th7ra41\":f,\"i1m51C8hkxi\":f,\"yanrI3\":92222,\"zz4C8hkxi\":f,\"iriihanC8hkxi\":f,\"SS\":154r,\"ik5hz1i\":[],\"za7k\":0m8ir}", "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789mqk3r0jlh6x87nazc5i14vbpuyf9t2gwdeso"))
```

last line looks like json !

how can i decode it ?

Comment: Just rewrite the given function in a reverse manner.

Comment: @zerkms how can i do this in reverse manner  ?

Comment: what kind of answer you're expecting? You must understand the logic and reverse it.

Comment: It was interesting challenge to reverse-engineering encoded JavaScript. Question was simple „how can I decode it” – not „please decode it for me”

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski i don't say decode it for me !!!! , i was looking for a way for decoding it ! so what suppose i do ? posting question without sample javascript code ?

Comment: For it ask @zekms, Sean, ArK, krthik and EdChum

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski sorry , i read your massage wrongly , i think you say "i requested to decode it" , sorry i was angry about people not reading question and giving negative rate , any way i didn't your comment completly

Comment: This is not full code - the options are missing - I can't decode from where other JS files will be downloaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most important line in this code is when function returns variable **J1**; Before it you can call expression `console.log(J1)`. Now you have almost decoded content. Next step is refactoring to change variable names like `e = "blur"`. Have in mind that JavaScript has functional scope, do not change to much, only variables from functions where it was decelerated.

Whole code is closed into IIFE with 4 arguments **window**, **document**, **element**, **navigator**.

After that we can find functions like this in decoded content:

```
function T8() {
    var Q = g['scripts'].length, Z = document.getLementsByTagName('script')[0], e;
    while (Q) {
        Q -= 1;
        e = document.createElement('script');
        e['type'] = 'text/javascript';
        e['async'] = true;
        e['src'] = g['scripts'][Q];
        Z['parentNode']['insertBefore'](e, Z);
     }
 }
```